# Pandas: Apply function to specific row values and indexes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I am trying to write a function to calculate a new variable into a new column. I have a dataset which tracks a variable for several subjects over many days.

```
Date        Athlete  Load
2016-01-04  Alan     180
2016-01-04  Ben      61
2016-01-04  David    186
2016-01-04  Joe      99
2016-01-04  John     131
```

I have been able to filter the subjects by name and create new data frames for each.

```
for athlete in df['Athlete'].unique():
    athlete = df.loc[ewma['Athlete'] == athlete]
    print(athlete.head())
```

The part I am having an issue with is the equation to calculate the new column. The first value is calculated from the first measured variable, but each subsequent value uses the previous day's value.

For example, the first row of the new column would use:

```
x = (df['Load'].iloc[0] * 2) - (df['Load'].iloc[0] / 2)
```

x = 180

The second row would use the previous day's value (x) in place of the second df['Load'] value. I was able to calculate the second value correctly with a basic function:

```
y = (df['Load'].iloc[1] * 2) - (x / 2)
```

y = 168

I tried using an 'if/else' but it did not calculate the correct values.

```
if df.index.name == '0':
    (df['Load'].iloc[0] * 2) - (df['Load'].iloc[0] / 2)
else:
     (df['Load'] * 2) - (df['Load'].shitf(-1) / 2)
```

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't `(df['Load'].iloc[0] * 2) - (df['Load'].iloc[0] / 2)` identical to `(df['Load'].iloc[0] * 1.5)` ?

Comment: your calculations for x and y might be wrong? `x=270` and `y=-13` instead?

Comment: @jpp I can't see a situation in which it wouldnt be == to *1.5

Comment: Expected output would be helpful.

Comment: @Peyman I just realized that I only included the head of the original dataset and not what I was actually trying to calculate. The dataset has 10 different subjects ('Alan', 'Ben', 'David', 'Joe', 'John', 'Michael', 'Niall', 'Paul', 'Steven', 'Tom'). I want to group each subjects' data into individual dataframes and then apply the equation. I have grouped them into individual dataframes with:

    for athlete in df['Athlete'].unique():
        athlete = df.loc[df['Athlete'] == athlete]

I now need to apply the conditional equation to each new dataframe for the subjects (athletes).

Comment: The load values for Alan for the first week are: 180, 0, 123, 71, 137, 0, 0. The expected outputs are: 180, -90, 291, -3.5, 275.75, -137.875, 68.9375. I realized that I provided the output for the wrong column.

Comment: @JDWelch for the first row where you have 180 don't you expect the output to be `2*180 - 180/2 = 270`?

Comment: @Peyman  After looking at the equation, I provided, Yes, the answer should be 270. After redoing the equation in a spreadsheet, the outputs for Alan should be 270, -135, 313.5, -14.75, 281.375, -140.6875, 70.34375. I meant for the second equation to be `(df['Load'] * 2) - (df['New column'].shitf(-1) / 2)`. I can't tell how to adapt your solution to use the calculated value from the previous row for the second part of the equation. Again, thank you for the help.

Comment: @JDWelch my solution is already using the calculated value from the previous row! I updated my answer with your data sample and you can see the expected output :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
def update_row(df):
    row_tmp = {"next_row": None}
    def updater(row):
        last_row_id = row.name - 1
        if row.name == 0:
            row_tmp['next_row'] = (row['Load'] * 2) - (row['Load'] /2.0)
            return row_tmp['next_row']
        row_tmp['next_row'] = (2* row['Load']) - (row_tmp['next_row']/2.0)
        return row_tmp['next_row']
    return updater


df

Date    Athlete Load
0   2016-01-04  Alan    180
1   2016-01-04  Alan    0
2   2016-01-04  Alan    123
3   2016-01-04  Alan    71
4   2016-01-04  Alan    137
5   2016-01-04  Alan    0
6   2016-01-04  Alan    0


df.apply(update_row(df), axis=1)

0    270.00000
1   -135.00000
2    313.50000
3    -14.75000
4    281.37500
5   -140.68750
6     70.34375
dtype: float64
```

P.S., I believe your calculation for x and y is not accurate, x should be 270 and y should be -13 based on your formula!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: I am not sure why the maths aren't working out in your function but the output for just Alan does not match the output I found in my excel spreadsheet. The outputs for Alan should be 270, -135, 313.5, -14.75, 281.375, -140.6875, 70.34375. I cannot find out how your outputs are being calculated.

Comment: @JDWelch did you check the output I printed out above? It matches exactly what you're expecting, i.e., the output is `270, -135, 313.5, -14.75, 281.375, -140.6875, 70.34375`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I figured out what was going wrong with the code and I finally figured out how to apply it to specific athletes as needed. I did find out that the `last_row` code didn't seem to do anything. Could you explain if I need that code or what it is supposed to do? Again, thank you for your patience with me through this process.

Comment: you're right! you don't need that line (updated the answer)!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to exclude first row and then:

```
previous_row = next_row * 2 - previous_row/2
```

can be achieved like this:

```
"""
(row n-1) = (row n) * 2 -  (row n-1) /2  except for row0.
"""
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt',delim_whitespace=True)

df['new'] = df.Load * 2 - df.Load.shift(1)/2
df.loc[0,'new'] = df.Load[0]
df
```

The result is:

```
    Date        Athlete Load    new
0   2016-01-04  Alan    180     180.0
1   2016-01-04  Ben     61      32.0
2   2016-01-04  David   186     341.5
3   2016-01-04  Joe     99      105.0
4   2016-01-04  John    131     212.5
```

Comment: @Bishan Poudel  This almost does the trick. The calculated values after the 2nd row are incorrect. As I look at the equation I am using to calculate the new column, I need the first `df.Load` to pull the measured value and `df.Load.shift(1)` to be `df.new.shift(1)`. I am sorry that I missed this detail in the original post. Do you have any ideas how I might be able to pull the current rows 'Load' value and the previous row 'new' value?

Comment: this solution is using the last sample of `Load` instead of the last sample of the newly calculated column (which is `new` here)